# List elements not being added correctly

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I've been trying to make a little neural network. It plays a copy of the No-Wifi Google dinosaure game. It is not the most efficient (and probably has a tons of leaks), but it works after a hundred generations more or less. But I've notived something: the best elements of the previous generations do not copy to the next or don't act as before, shown by how the best before always jumped and then the next generation doesn't jump at all. Where is the problem? Btw it is a large code but I don't know how to attach files, can you comment on how?

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dino</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="genetic.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dino.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="population_dino.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dino.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="score">Score: 0</div>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body> 
    
</html>
```

genetic.js:

```js
function sigmoid(t) {
    return 1/(1+Math.pow(Math.E, -t));
}
function weightedRand(spec) {
  var i, j, table=[];
  for (i in spec) {
    for (j=0; j<spec[i]*10; j++) {
      table.push(i);
    }
  }
  //console.log(table,spec)
    return table[Math.floor(Math.random() * table.length)];
}
function randomfromminustoone(){
    return Math.random()*2-1;
}

class Connection {
    constructor(weight) {
        if (weight==null){
            this.weight=randomfromminustoone();
        } else{
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    get_weight() {
      return this.weight;
    }

    set_weight(weight) {
      return this.weight = weight;
    }
}  
class Neuron {
    constructor(numOuputs = 0, neuronIndex, weights = []) {

        this.outputWeights = [];
        this.outputVal = null;

        this.neuronIndex = neuronIndex;
        for (let c = 0; c < numOuputs; c++) {
            var weight = weights[c] || null;

            this.outputWeights.push(new Connection(weight));
        }
    }

    setOutputVal(outputVal) {
        this.outputVal = outputVal;
    }

    getOutputVal(inputs,inputWeights) {
        this.outputVal=0;
        for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            this.outputVal+=inputs[i]*inputWeights[i];
        }
        this.outputVal=sigmoid(this.outputVal);
        return this.outputVal;
    }

    getNeuronIndex() {
        return this.neuronIndex;
    }
    getOuputWeight(i){
        return this.outputWeights[i].get_weight();
    }
    updateInputWeights(prevLayer) {

        for (let n = 0; n < prevLayer.length-1; n++) {
            let neuron = prevLayer[n];

           // neuron.outputWeights[this.neuronIndex].weight += ;
        }
    }
}


class Net {

    constructor(topology = [],model=false) {
        if (model){
            this.layers=model.layers;
            //console.log("flag");
        } else {
        this.topology = topology;

        // number of layers
        this.numLayers = topology.length;
        this.layers = [];
        for (let layerNum = 0; layerNum < this.numLayers; layerNum++) {
            var layer = [];
            var numOuputs = topology[layerNum + 1] ? topology[layerNum + 1] : 0;
            for (let neuronNum = 0; neuronNum < topology[layerNum]; neuronNum++) {
                let neuron = new Neuron(numOuputs, neuronNum);
                layer.push(neuron);
            }
            this.layers.push(layer);
        }
    }
    }
    /*
    getResults() {
        this.resultVals = [];
        var lastLayer = this.layers[this.layers.length-1];

        for (let n = 0; n < lastLayer.length-1; n++) {
            this.resultVals.push(lastLayer[n].getOutputVal());
        }

        return this.resultVals;
    }*/

    feedLayer(inputs,layerNum){
        let layer=this.layers[layerNum];
        let outputs=[];
        for (let i = 0; i < layer.length; i++) {
            let neuron = layer[i];
            let neuronWeights=[];
            for (let a = 0; a < this.layers[layerNum-1].length; a++) {
                neuronWeights.push(this.layers[layerNum-1][a].getOuputWeight(i));
            }
            outputs.push(neuron.getOutputVal(inputs,neuronWeights));
        }
        return outputs;
    }
    feedAll(inputs){
        let prevOutputs=inputs;
        for (let i = 1; i < this.layers.length; i++) {
            prevOutputs=this.feedLayer(prevOutputs,i);
        }
        return prevOutputs;
    }
};

class Population{
    constructor (PopNumber,topology,bestResults=[]){
        if (bestResults.length>1){
            this.population=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < bestResults.length; i++) {
                this.population.push(bestResults[i][1]);
                console.log(bestResults[i][1].feedAll([0.05,0]))
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < PopNumber-bestResults.length; i++) {
                let addNet= this.choose(bestResults);

                /*if (randomfromminustoone()>0.5){

                    addNet=this.mix_elements(addNet,this.choose(bestResults));
                }*/
                addNet=this.mutate_values(addNet);
                this.population.push(addNet);
            }
        } else {
            this.population=[];
                for (var i = 0; i < PopNumber; i++) {
                    let addNet= new Net(topology);
                    this.population.push(addNet);
                }
        }
    }


    choose(results){
        let dic={};
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            dic[i]=results[i][0];
        }
        return results[weightedRand(dic)][1];
    }
    mix_elements(elem1,elem2){
        var output=  new Net();
        output.topology = elem2.topology;
        output.numLayers = elem2.numLayers;
        output.layers = elem2.layers;

        for (var i = 0; i < elem1.layers.length; i++) {
            for (var a = 0; a < elem1.layers[i].length; a++) {
                if (randomfromminustoone()>0.5){
                output.layers[i][a]=elem1.layers[i][a];
            }
            }
            
        }
        return output;
    }
    mutate_values(model){
        if (model==null){
            return [];
        }
        var output=  new Net();
        output.topology = model.topology;
        output.numLayers = model.numLayers;
        output.layers = model.layers;

        for (var layer = 0; layer < output.layers.length; layer++) {
            for (var neuron = 0; neuron < output.layers[layer].length; neuron++) {
                for (var i = 0; i < output.layers[layer][neuron].outputWeights.length; i++) {
                    if (randomfromminustoone()>0.75){
                        output.layers[layer][neuron].outputWeights[i].weight =output.layers[layer][neuron].outputWeights[i].get_weight()+randomfromminustoone()/5;

                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        return output;
    }
};
```

dino.js:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
};
function Dino(brain,pop){
    this.cooldown=0;
    this.score=0;
    this.alive=true;
    this.y=300;
    this.before_jump=this.y;
    this.inertia=0;
    this.population=pop;
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.className="Dino";
    this.div.main=this;
    this.div.style.top=this.y+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    this.brain = brain;
};
Dino.prototype.jump = function(dino){
    if (dino.y==dino.before_jump){
        //dino.y=dino.before_jump;
        dino.inertia=3;
        dino.jumpInterval=setInterval( jump => {
            dino.y-=dino.inertia
            dino.div.style.top=dino.y+"px";
            dino.inertia -= 0.05;
            if (dino.y>dino.before_jump){
                dino.inertia=0;
                clearInterval(dino.jumpInterval);
                dino.y=dino.before_jump;}
        });
    }
};
Dino.prototype.down = function(dino){
    if (dino.y<dino.before_jump && dino.inertia>-5){
            dino.inertia-=1.5;
        }
};

Dino.prototype.lost =function(dino){
    dino.alive=false;
    dino.div.remove();
    dino.score=dino.population.score;
    dino.population.still_alive-=1;
    dino.population.records.push(dino.brain);
    delete dino;
};
Dino.prototype.check_collision = function(dino) {
    cactuses=document.getElementsByClassName("cactus");
    for (var i = cactuses.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cactuses[i].main.x<=280 && dino.y>=280 && dino.alive){
            dino.lost(dino);
        }
    };
};

Dino.prototype.smart = function(dino){
    var cactuses=Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("cactus"));
    cactuses.sort(function(cactus){
        return cactus.main.x;
    });
    if (cactuses.length>0){
        var distance_nearest_cactus=(cactuses[0].main.x-240)/660;
    } else{
        var distance_nearest_cactus=1;

    };
    let results = dino.brain.feedAll([distance_nearest_cactus,(300-dino.y)/100*(-dino.inertia/3)]);
    let high_score=results.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,results))
    if (high_score==0){
        dino.jump(dino);

    } else if (high_score==1){
        dino.down(dino);
    };
};

function Dot(height){
    this.y=height
    this.x=900
    //-- cree le DIV
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.className = 'dot';
    this.div.style.top=this.y+"px";
    this.div.style.left=this.x+"px";
    this.div.main=this;
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
};
Dot.prototype.delete =function(leave_div)
{
    if (leave_div == false){
    this.div.remove();
    }
    delete this;
};
function CreateDot(){
    new Dot(getRndInteger(346,350));
};

function Cactus(){
    this.x=900
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.style.left=this.x+"px";
    this.div.className="cactus";
    this.div.main=this;
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
};
Cactus.prototype.delete =function(leave_div)
{
    if (leave_div == false){
    this.div.remove();}
    delete this;
}
function CreateCactus(){
    new Cactus();
}
function move_object(object){
    object.main.x -= 1;
    object.main.div.style.left = object.main.x+'px'; 
    if (object.main.x<230)
    { 
        object.main.delete(false); 
    }   
};
```

population_dino.js:

```js
class Dino_population{
    constructor(nbPopulation,id,prevPop=[]){
        this.population=[];
        this.id=id;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=this.id;
        this.brains=new Population(nbPopulation,[2,5,5,3],prevPop);
        for (var i = 0; i < nbPopulation; i++) {
            this.population.push(new Dino(this.brains.population[i],this));
        
        }
        this.number=nbPopulation;
        this.still_alive=nbPopulation;
        this.score=0;
        this.speed=4.5;
        var self= this;
        this.move_interval=setInterval(function(){self.move_all(self)},self.speed);
        this.last_cactus=1000;
        this.records=[];
    }
    move_all(self){
    if (getRndInteger(0,60)<10){
        CreateDot();
    }
    self.last_cactus-=getRndInteger(1,10);
    if (self.last_cactus<10){
        self.last_cactus=getRndInteger(500,5000);
        CreateCactus();
    }

    var cactuses=document.getElementsByClassName("cactus");
    for (var i = cactuses.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        move_object(cactuses[i]);
    };
    var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (var v = dots.length - 1; v >= 0; v--) {
        move_object(dots[v]);
    }
    
    self.score+=1;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: "+Math.floor(self.score/10).toString();
    for (var i = self.population.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let dino=self.population[i];
        dino.cooldown-=1;
        if (dino.cooldown<=0){
            dino.cooldown=10;
            dino.smart(dino);
        }
        
        dino.check_collision(dino);
        
    }
    if (self.still_alive==0){
        clearInterval(self.move_interval);
        var cactuses=document.getElementsByClassName("cactus");
        while (cactuses.length>0){
            delete cactuses[0].main;
            cactuses[0].remove();
            
        };
        var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        while (dots.length>0){
            delete dots[0].main;
            dots[0].remove();
            
        };
        self.new_pop(self);
        }
}   
    new_pop(old){
        let old_bests= old.records.slice(Math.max(old.records.length - 10, 0));
        let old_best_weighted=[]
        for(let i=0;i<old_bests.length;i++){
            console.log([old_bests[i].feedAll([0.05,0])])
            old_best_weighted.push([10-i,old_bests[i]]);
        }
        let old_nb=old.number;
        let old_id=old.id;
        globalThis.pop= new Dino_population(old_nb,old_id+1,old_best_weighted);

        }
}
var pop=new Dino_population(200,1);
```

dino.css:

```css
.Dino{
    background-image: url("Dinausaure.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    left: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
#ground{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    top:270px;
    left: 240px;
    position: absolute;
}
#line{
    width: 670px;
    height: 0px;
    top:345px;
    left:230px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dot{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cactus{
    background-image: url("cactus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    top:310px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
#score{
    top:180px;
    left:230px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here are the images:
[image: dinausaure image] [image: cactus image]

Do no doubht in telling me any optimisation, mistake or bug. I am new at neural networks and do not have much experience with Js.
Any question ask me on comments.

Comment: The value is pushed on dino lost state, however not sure if it's utilized. You could probably console.log these things and new_pop function to see what's being returned.

Comment: @blanknamefornow I do  check. First I've checked if the best ones were the ones selected (because before the weighted random was made with the score) and then I verified the ones that were the best were correctly send and were the same as the bestResults of the next generation. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Of coarse error can be elsewhere but I'd troubleshoot from those points backwards to see where the details get skewed. So if new_pop's old value on every return is wrong, see where that old value is being generated from and step it back with console.log, It's a lot of code to tear through so I just be debugging/tracing those values closely to see which part does fail.

Comment: The weird thing is that, in the loop where I add each best value of the previous population, I used a console.log to see if it was the same. And it is. So basically I have the best values passed throught push, and then I don't really know how to keep track of them so I look at the images, and there I see sometimes none behaves like the previous bests.